# @JsonIgnore is ignored in JUnit-Controller-Unit Test with Mockito

Tags: spring, unit-testing, maven, junit, jackson

i have constructed my first Spring-Controller Unit Tests and one Controller gives back one object in JSON-Format. The Relations are annotated with @JsonIgnore and it works in my software.

When I simply wanna test those Controllers I'll always get an infinite-Recursion Error on exactly that attribute. It's a 1:1 Relation. On other relations the @JsonIgnore works without any problems.

Tests in error: 
  save(package.a.b.c.test.ControllerATest): Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: package.a.b.c.entity.A["b"]->package.a.b.c.B["a"] etc...

It seems, like my @JsonIgnore is ignored in test-scope?

It's a Maven-managed Project, so i include like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe, somebody made the same experience?

Answer (score 0):

Is the annotation on the fields or their getters?  Jackson only looks at the getters by default so moving your annotation to the getters will solve the problem.  For example:

```
class Person {
    @JsonIgnore
    Set<Department> departments;

    public Set<Department> getDepartments() { return this.departments; }
}

class Department {
    @JsonIgnore
    Set<Person> persons;

    public Set<Person> getPersons() return this.persons; }
}
```

will cause an infinite recursion if a `Person` and a `Department` object are referencing each other.

The following will work:

```
class Person {
    Set<Department> departments;

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<Department> getDepartments() { return this.departments; }
}

class Department {
    Set<Person> persons;

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<Person> getPersons() return this.persons; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just found out, it has to do with bi-directional 1:1 relationships in objects. Switching to newer Version 2.3.1, provided with the following dependencies, solved that issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```